# how to fix python login script using txt files to login and register users

Tags: python

I wrote a python script for logging people in and registering. it used a txt file to store the usernames and passwords. I wrote it in http://trinket.io. However, It does not work in regular python. can anyone tell me what i need to change to fix it?
edit:
here is the code

```
file = open('accounts.txt', 'a+')
lines = file.readlines()
login = {}
for line in lines:
  key, value = line.strip().split(', ')
  login[key] = value


while True:
  command = input('$ ')
  command_list = command.split(' ')

  if command_list[0] == 'login':
    username = command_list[1]
    password = command_list[2]

    try:
      if login[username] == password:
        print('login')
      else:
        print('no login')
    except KeyError:
      print('no login')
  elif command_list[0] == "register":
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(command_list[1])
    file.write(", ")
    file.write(command_list[2])
  elif command_list[0] == "help":
    print("""To login, type login, then type the username and then type the password. 
To register, type register, then type the username and then the password.""")
  elif command_list[0]== "quit":
    break
  else:
    print('unrecognised command')
```

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Which part is not working as expected?

Comment: when i register an account, it doesn't show up in the file. also, when I log in with a valid account i had manually added, it only returns the "No login"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following edits, marked by `##### ADDED LINE` should solve your issue.

Explanations:

(1) You need to use `.seek()` before you read from a file that was opened in `a+` mode.

(2) Using `.flush()` will force whatever data is in the buffer to be written to file immediately.

(3) Without me restructuring your program too much, this edit allows you to immediately access the newly registered user to login with. This is because, as the program is structured now, you only add details to your `login` dictionary when you first open the accounts file.

```
file = open('stack.txt', 'a+')
file.seek(1) ##### ADDED LINE (1) 
lines = file.readlines()
login = {}
for line in lines:
    key, value = line.strip().split(', ')
    login[key] = value

...

  elif command_list[0] == "register":
      file.write("\n")
      file.write(command_list[1])
      file.write(", ")
      file.write(command_list[2])
      file.flush() ##### ADDED LINE (2)
      login[command_list[1]] = command_list[2] ##### ADDED LINE (3)
```

Hope this helps!